# vuejs token error when implementing auth0

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, auth0

I'm new to vuejs and have implemented this example:

[Auth0 vuejs and api example](https://github.com/auth0-developer-hub/spa_vue_javascript_hello-world_composition-api/tree/basic-authentication)

It works just fine, but I run into some issues when trying to merge the vuejs code to my own project.

When loading the page requiring authentication, I get this error:

> index.vue?4db4:11 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'getAccessTokenSilently' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.

The code for my page, looks like this:

```
<script>
import Layout from "../../../layouts/main.vue";
import { getProtectedResource } from "@/services/message.service";
import { ref } from "vue";

import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-vue";

const message = ref("");

const getMessage = async () => {
  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently();
  const { data, error } = await getProtectedResource(accessToken);

  if (data) {
    message.value = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
  }

  if (error) {
    message.value = JSON.stringify(error, null, 2);
  }
};

getMessage();

export default {
  components: {
    Layout
  },
  data() {
    return {
    
    };
  },
  methods: {
    rightcolumn() {
      if (document.querySelector('.layout-rightside-col').classList.contains('d-none')) 
{
      document.querySelector('.layout-rightside-col').classList.remove('d-none')
      } else {
      document.querySelector('.layout-rightside-col').classList.add('d-none')
      }
    }
  }

};
</script>

<template>
<Layout>
  <p id="page-description">
        <span
          >This page retrieves a <strong>protected message</strong> from an
          external API.</span
        >
        <span
          ><strong
            >Only authenticated users can access this page.</strong
          ></span
        >
      </p>
      <CodeSnippet title="Protected Message" :code="message" />
</Layout>
</template>
```

I've tried the example from the documentation provided here [enter link description here](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs#add-login-to-your-application)

```
<script>
  import Layout from "../../../layouts/main.vue";
  //import { getProtectedResource } from "@/services/message.service";
  //import { ref } from "vue";

  import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-vue";

  export default {
    setup() {
      const { loginWithRedirect } = useAuth0();

      return {
        login: () => {
          loginWithRedirect();
        }
      };
    },
    components: {
      Layout
    },
    data() {
      return {
       
      };
    },
    methods: {
      rightcolumn() {
        if (document.querySelector('.layout-rightside-col').classList.contains('d-none')) {
          document.querySelector('.layout-rightside-col').classList.remove('d-none')
        } else {
          document.querySelector('.layout-rightside-col').classList.add('d-none')
        }
      }
    }
}

</script>
```

But still receives this error:

> index.vue?4db4:11 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure
> property 'loginWithRedirect' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined.
> at setup (index.vue?4db4:11:1)

I'm registrering the plugin this way in main:

```
createApp(App)
    .use(store)
    .use(router)
    .use(VueApexCharts)
    .use(BootstrapVue3)
    .component(VueFeather.type, VueFeather)
    .use(Maska)
    .use(Particles)
    .use(i18n)
    .use(
        createAuth0({
          domain: 'xyz.auth0.com',
          client_id: 'secret',
          redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4040/callback',
          audience: 'https://audience',
        })
      )
    .use(vClickOutside).mount('#app');
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "vuejs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-vue": "^1.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic": "^32.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue": "^2.0.1",
    "@fullcalendar/bootstrap": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.10.1",
    "@fullcalendar/vue3": "^5.10.1",
    "@j-t-mcc/vue3-chartjs": "^1.2.0",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.2",
    "@simonwep/pickr": "^1.8.2",
    "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet": "^0.6.1",
    "@vueform/multiselect": "^2.3.1",
    "@vueform/slider": "^2.0.8",
    "@vueform/toggle": "^2.0.1",
    "@vuelidate/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.34",
    "@vuelidate/validators": "^2.0.0-alpha.26",
    "@zhuowenli/vue-feather-icons": "^5.0.2",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "apexcharts": "^3.33.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
    "bootstrap-vue-3": "^0.3.3",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.0",
    "click-outside-vue3": "^4.0.1",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "echarts": "^5.3.0",
    "feather-icons": "^4.28.0",
    "firebase": "^9.6.6",
    "highlight.js": "^11.4.0",
    "leaflet": "^1.7.1",
    "lottie-web": "^5.8.1",
    "maska": "^1.5.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "node-sass": "6.0.1",
    "particles.vue3": "^1.40.2",
    "prismjs": "^1.26.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.2.1",
    "simplebar": "^5.3.6",
    "simplebar-vue3": "^0.1.5",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.32",
    "swiper": "^6.8.4",
    "vue": "3.2.36",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.15",
    "vue-draggable-next": "^2.1.1",
    "vue-easy-lightbox": "^1.3.0",
    "vue-feather": "^2.0.0",
    "vue-flatpickr-component": "^9.0.5",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.2.0-beta.15",
    "vue-prismjs": "^1.2.0",
    "vue3-apexcharts": "^1.4.1",
    "vue3-count-to": "^1.1.2",
    "vue3-echarts": "^1.0.4",
    "vue3-google-map": "^0.8.3",
    "vue3-quill": "^0.2.6",
    "vuevectormap": "^1.0.8",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2",
    "yarn": "^1.22.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/vue3-essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `@auth0/auth0-vue` has a limitation. `useAuth0` must be used in the [`setup`](https://vuejs.org/api/composition-api-setup.html#composition-api-setup) hook. Read the [documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs#add-login-to-your-application) for info.

> To add login to your application, use the loginWithRedirect function that is exposed on the return value of useAuth0, which you can access in your component's `setup` function.

```
<script>
import { ref } from "vue";
import { useAuth0 } from "@auth0/auth0-vue";

export default {
    setup() {
        const message = ref("");
        const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();

        const getMessage = async () => {
            const accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently();
            const { data, error } = await getProtectedResource(accessToken);
          
            if (data) {
              message.value = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
            }
          
            if (error) {
              message.value = JSON.stringify(error, null, 2);
            }
        };

        getMessage();

        return {
            message
        }
    },
    ...
}

</script>
<template>...</template>
```

Comment: Hi Naren, thanks for the help. I tried your example and the example mentioned on the documentation, but with the same result. I updated my questions, since there might be some errors elsewhere?

Comment: Maybe a version conflict. Verify that the `@auth0/auth0-vue` installed version is compatible with the version of vue you are using.

Comment: Try printing `import auth from "@auth0/auth0-vue"; console.log(auth)`; Possible you'll see `undefined` which means it's a version conflict.

Comment: You're right, it prints undefined. I have updated my question with the content of my package.json file. Can you see a conflict there?